# Global Facebook App ID to integrate with CRM database

Tags: facebook, facebook-social-plugins

I am working with a company trying to launch OAuth/Facebook Connect across their site to add social functionality. What is the best way to develop apps to allow for integration with their CRM database. Does any one have best practices in regards to integrating multiple apps across a site? Do they all need the same AppID or can you integrate from multiple apps with different IDs. Also do they all need to tie to the same domain? If we have european sites do we need to create a different app ID or can we use the same from US site.

Answer (score 0):

Each app is tied to a domain, but you can have multiple apps tied to the same domain (i.e. commonly a dev version and prod version). The only thing that makes things unique is the app ID and secret key. You just need to check which ones to use under which context. All the code can be exactly the same, you're just instantiating the Facebook instance with a different ID/key.

Comment: Thanks for this! Have you heard of companies using the social data granted access by the user in CRM integration? In order to do this do all apps need to have the exact same name? Can you explain which ones to use under which context?

Comment: Users grant access to an app, you can then query for their information through the app and integrate it how you want. Since you have to request permission from the user for each app, you don't want to have a lot of apps. Ideally only 1. I thought you meant you have a shipping CRM product where each client would setup their own app for integration.